# WildFly scripting tool

Tags: wildfly

Есть ли в WildFly какой-либо аналог wsadmin из WAS?
Где можно найти информацию?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вас интересует управление и настройка WildFly через консоль.

Для этого нужно использовать jboss-cli.sh
Пример для одной команды:

```
/jboss-cli.sh -c command="/subsystem=ejb3/thread-pool=default :read-resource(include-runtime=true, recursive=true)"
```

или

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c "/subsystem=ejb3/thread-pool=default :read-resource(include-runtime=true, recursive=true)"
```

Если нужно сразу несколько из файла, то так:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --file=myfile.cli
```

myfile.cli - простой текстовый файл, где каждая строка это команда.